# I want to remove the parent if the href attribute have no value

Tags: html, jquery, css

I was trying to remove the parent div if the href attribute has no value. here is the code I have tried can you tell me what did i wrong?

```
$("#cs-gallery .et_pb_module_inner .dnext_thumbs_gallery_top_holder .dnext-thumbs-gallery-top .dnext-thumbs-gallery-active  .dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child .dnext-thumbs-gallery-item a").filter(function () {
    return this.attr('href').length == 0;
}).remove();
```

Comment: I would think you need to use `.parent().remove()`. because right now you only removes the `link (<a>)`

Answer (score 1):

Created relevant html and js. Just try once with your selectors

Try below code snippet

```js
$("#elements a").filter(function () {
    if($(this).attr('href').length == 0)
    {
        console.log('test');
        $(this).parent().remove();  
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elements">
    <div><a href="">AAA</a></div>
    <div><a href="bbb.html">BBB</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">CCC</a></div>
    <div><a href="">DDD</a></div>
</div>
```